# Proving $A \cup (A \setminus B) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove $A \cup (A \setminus B) = A$. Here is my attempt.

\begin{align*}
x \in A \cup (A \setminus B) & \iff x \in A \vee x \in (A \setminus B) \\
& \iff x \in A \vee \left(x \in A \wedge x \not \in B\right) \\
& \iff \left(x \in A \vee x \in A\right) \wedge \left(x \in A \vee x \not \in B\right) \\
& \iff x \in A \wedge \left(x \in A \vee x \not \in B\right) \\
& \iff \left(x \in A \wedge x \in A\right) \vee \left(x \in A \wedge x \not \in B\right) \\
& \iff x \in A \vee \left(x \in A \wedge x \not \in B\right) \\
& \iff x \in A 
\end{align*}
I feel that there are some extraneous steps here. How does this look?

Comment: The second and second last lines are identical.

Comment: Well... your second line and your sixth line are identical, so if the last step is valid, then you definitely have extra steps.

Comment: A simpler (but not necessarily shorter) approach is to show that given two sets, $S$ and $T$, you have that $S = T$ if and only if **both** $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$.  Then, you show that $S \subseteq T$ by assuming that $e \in S$ and using this assumption to prove that then $e \in T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, your rewriting ended up back where you started, and 5xum suggests a probably better way. In case you are interested though, it's also possible, but not easy, to do it your way through algebraic rewriting.
Here is how:

\begin{align*}
&x \in A \vee \left(x \in A \wedge x \not \in B\right) \\
&\iff (x \in A \land (x \in B \lor x \notin B)) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \\
&\iff (x \in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \\
&\iff (x \in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \\
&\iff x \in A \land (x \in B \lor x \notin B) \\
&\iff x \in A
\end{align*}

The hard part is going from the first to the second line, where we have to insert a conjunction with $(x \in B \lor x \notin B)$ (applying the law of the excluded middle). The reason to add this is that we somehow need to get rid of the irrelevant $x \notin B$ constraint in the second part of the expression, but it doesn't cancel out with anything currently, so we need to insert something that might cancel with it (some expression involving $B$). Or you can think of it as casework on whether $x$ is in $B$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the steps you write are extraneous. Your line $2$ is identical to line $6$.

On the other hand, you don't really explain how you get from line $6$ to line $7$ (the conclusion), so to be honest, it doesn't look too good.

---

Instead, what you could do is prove the equivalence in one way, and then the other. In other words, prove that $A\subseteq A\cup (A\setminus B)$, and prove that $A\cup (A\setminus B)\subseteq A$.  At least one of the two relations should be more or less trivial to prove.

**Alternatively**, you could also

1. Remember (or, alternatively, *prove*) that if $C\subseteq A$, then $C\cup A = A$
2. Notice that $A\setminus B\subseteq A$

and the conclusion follows directly.

Answer (score 1):

After the first $\iff$ sign, you have$$x\in A\vee x\in(A\setminus B)\tag1$$and, after the sixth one, you have$$x\in A\vee(x\in A\wedge x\notin B),$$ after which you jump right away to $x\in A$. Why not to go directly from $(1)$ to $x\in A$? After all $x\in A\setminus B\implies x\in A$ and therefore $(1)\implies x\in A$; the reverse implication is trivial.

I would do it as follows: if $A\subset A\cup(A\setminus B)$ and, since $A\setminus B\subset A$, $A\cup(A\setminus B)\subset A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your second and second last lines are identical, so everything between is unnecessary.

However, while the next step is valid, it is basically *what you were trying to prove*.

So this is what you may have been trying for:

$$\begin{align}A\cup(A\smallsetminus B)&\iff A\cup(A\cap B^\complement)\\&\iff (A\cap(B\cup B^\complement))\cup(A\cap B^\complement)\\&\qquad\vdots\\&\qquad\vdots\\&\iff A\cap (B\cup B^\complement)\\&\iff A\end{align}$$